# Get the last character of a String from a file in Python?

Tags: string, python-3.x, file-io

I'm trying to write a function that takes a character and places all words in `ifile` that ends with the character `c` into another new file. I thought this would based on string indexing, but the text file result is always blank. Why is it that `line[0]` will work but `line[-1]` won't? I don't understand why the same concept doesn't apply.

```
def getListEnd(c,ifile,ofile):
    for line in ifile:
        if c in line[-1]:
            ofile.write(str(line))
```

Comment: Did you correctly close your `ofile`?

Comment: Iterating files in python leaves the line ending characters on.  Have you assured that ifile is an iterator that takes CR and LF off?

Comment: What do you mean line[0] will work but line[-1] won't? line[-1] returns the last char of your string.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to call `ofile.close()` in the same scope as where you wrote `ofile = open('some_file.txt', 'w')`, but after your call to `getListEnd` of course.

So you'll have your code looking like this:

```
def getListEnd(c,ifile,ofile):
    for line in ifile:
        if c in line[-1]:
            ofile.write(str(line))

infile = open('inputfile.txt', 'r')
outfile = open('outputfile.txt', 'w')
getListEnd('$', infile, outfile)
outfile.close()
infile.close()
```

If you don't call `close()`, your buffers might not get flushed correctly and thus your file won't be written to.